# How can I pass params from Nextjs 12 middleware to the route handler

Tags: next.js, middleware

i am using the new stable nextjs 12 middleware and try to pass params from this middleware to the route handler.

My use case: I am using the middleware for authentication with a json web token. This token includes for example the company id and I want to pass this company id to the following route handler to verify the user input.

My code looks like this:

```
export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
 if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/user")) {
   let {valid, token} = (await authVerify(
     req.cookies.get("token")
   ))
   if (valid) {
     return NextResponse.next();
   }
   return NextResponse.json({ valid: false, message: "invalid token" });
 }
}

export default async function getAllUserHandler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) 
  const companyId = //req.company_id or something
  return await userQuery(companyId);
}
```

Comment: Does the NextApiRequest not also have access via `req.cookies.get("token")`?

Comment: Yes but then i have to do that twice and i have to include it in every route handler. My idea would do it much more comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not shure if it works but i would try this. See the line below `// Maybe this also works`.

```javascript
export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/user")) {
        const { valid, token } = await authVerify(req.cookies.get("token"));

        if (valid) {
            const response = NextResponse.next();
            // You can add cookies
            response.cookies.set('vercel', 'fast', { path: '/test' });
            // Maybe this also works
            response.company_id = token.company_id;
            return response;

        }
        return NextResponse.json({ valid: false, message: "invalid token" });
    }
}

export default async function getAllUserHandler(
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse
) {
    const companyId = req.company_id;
    return await userQuery(companyId);
}
```

Comment: How about some feedback. Did this work for you?